# C++ Car Inventory, copy constructor probs

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, copy-constructor, inventory

So I have been struggling with this asignment for some time. I fix all my memory probs (logic for days) and now I am stuck on what seems the easiest. I have to expand two arrays when they are full, this expands them, but does not copy the data, any suggestions on where to go from here?

```
List::List(const List& x, int b)
```

{

```
if(b == 1)    // if car needs to grow
{
    size1 = x.size1 * 2;
    car = new Car[size1];
    for(int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
        car[i] = x.car[i];          // what copies .. I think...
}
else if(b == 2)            // if motorcycle array needs to grow
{
    size2 = x.size2 * 2;
    motor = new Motorcycle[size2];
    for(int i = 0; i < count2; i++)
    {
        motor[i] = x.motor[i];   // what copies .. I think...
    }   
}
```

}

I have an asignment operator overload in both those classes as well

```
Car& Car::operator=( Car x)
{
    this->setModel(x.rModel()); 
    this->setMake(x.rMake());   
    this->setPrice(x.Vehicle::getPrice());
    this->setMileage(x.rMiles());
    this->setLot(x.rLot());
    this->setGas(x.rGas());
    this->seats = x.rSeats();
    this->luxury = x.rLux();    


}
```

Similarly in Motorcycle

```
Motorcycle& Motorcycle::operator=( Motorcycle x)
{
    this->setModel(x.rModel()); 
    this->setMake(x.rMake());   
    this->setPrice(x.Vehicle::getPrice());
    this->setMileage(x.rMiles());
    this->setLot(x.rLot());
    this->setGas(x.rGas());
    this->style = x.rStyle();
    this->passenger = x.rPassenger();   

}
```

If you help me out I will send you a lock of the hair I pulled out.

Full Code: https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7LaFMkHcgCAd3habUpjWUR0YU0&usp=sharing

Comment: why not use `std::vector<Car> cars`?

Comment: Proffesor is trying to teach us the back end of vectors

Comment: How are you determining that the elements aren't copied? Show the code that's using the class.

Answer (score 1):

In your code you are probably missing a reassignment statement

```
car = new Car[size1];
for(int i = 0; i < count1; i++)
    car[i] = x.car[i];
```

after this you should add another line to make x point to car again

```
x = car;
```

similar for motor too!

hope this helps but try to use vectors if you want dynammic arrays (obv they are fast :p)

Comment: Yes, but car belongs to the new instance of the List class this is all in, as of now it makes the new instance with an expanded array but does not copy the data

Comment: @jbrizown if you could post link to your complete code it will be a great.

Comment: Bro I tried to debugge your code but it has a hell lot of bugs so I gave up!